# A la hora de mostrar un select con un foreach me muestra los datos en select diferentes

Tags: laravel

aqui esta mi funcion donde realizo la consulta y si me trae los años

```
$anos =\DB::table('organizador_tareas')
            ->join('años_trabajo', 'años_trabajo.id', '=', 'organizador_tareas.ano')
            ->select('años_trabajo.anos_trabajo')
            ->get();     


return \View::make('empleado_inicio',compact('paises','nivel_academico'
                ,'titulo_obtenido','departamento_honduras','tipo_contratacion','dep_icf','bancos'))->with(
                [
                    'anos' => $anos,
                    'contador' => 0
                ]
            );
        }
```

aqui esta mi select donde quiero mostrar los datos el problema es que me muestra los años en select diferentes y no en uno solo y no se como podria mostrar los datos en un solo select

```
                    @foreach($anos as $anos)
                     <div class="form-group">
                         {!! Form::label('año', 'Año:', ['class' => 'col-lg-2 control-label']) !!}
                         <div class="col-lg-10">
                             {{Form::select('año',$anos, 
                    ['required'=>'required'])}}
                         </div>
                     </div>
                     @endforeach
```

Aqui esta como lo corregi para ver si solo asi me funcionaba

```
<select>

                             @foreach($anos_consulta as $item)
                                 <option value="{{$item}}">
                                     {{anos_trabajo}}
                                 </option>
                             @endforeach

                         </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un **Select**, debes recorrer cada item de tu colección con un each e ir agregando las opciones. Debes tener en cuenta que debes indicar la variable o lista que vas a recorrer y una variable que va a representar a cada item es decir, en cada iteracion. En el siguiente ejemplo "anos" representa a un listado de años, "item" representa cada item de esa lista o cada "año". Solo debes corregir tu each del siguiente modo:

```
<select>

    @foreach($anos as $item)

        <option value="{{$item}}">
            {{item}}
        </option>

    @endforeach

</select>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Comment: intente hacerlo de esa forma el problema que me tira un error  por que la sintaxis como iria en un  select de laravel por que asi no mas me tira errores

Comment: Que error te tira? Laravel no tiene select. Lo que estas haciendo en este caso  ya sea en laravel o cualquiero otro framework es simplemente HTML. Usando sintaxis de blade para incrustar dinamicamente el contenido.

Comment: "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\ICF\resources\views\modales\modal-registro-empleados_pestañas.blade.php)

Comment: bien, no se cual es el contenido de `$item` el problema es que son objetos. Osea, debes imprimir algo como `{{ $item->text }}` donde `text` sea la propiedad que deseas mostrar en ese lugar.